# Quasar toggle q-file when another button is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework

In Quasar framework how can I toggle the file selector `q-file` when I click certain button.

**My effort so far:**

when this buton is click it should toggle the `q-file`

```
<button @click="toggleFileSelector">toggle file selector</button>
```

so I have this File-selector and I want this to toggle when I click on a button

```
<q-file outlined class="field" ref="myFileSelector" :label="label" v-model="myFile">
  <template v-slot:append>
    <div class="attachment notosanskr-medium">File</div>
  </template>
</q-file>
```

the method to toggle:

```
  methods: {
    toggleFileSelector() {
      this.$refs.myFileSelector.toggle();
    },
  },
```

but I get an error:

> "TypeError: this.$refs.myFileSelector.toggle is not a function"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can toggle input by ref. You need to call `pickFiles` function.

Example -   `this.$refs.file.pickFiles();`

```
<q-file ref="file" clearable filled color="purple-12" v-model="model" label="Label"></q-file>

      
<q-btn @click="testclick" color="primary" label="Click"></q-btn>


methods:{
    testclick(){
      this.$refs.file.pickFiles();
    }
  }
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/dyXpXgr

Comment: Thank you it works!!!, is this on the official documentation, can you tell where?

Comment: You can check the method section in the QFile-API.